# Using a string to call a table in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here's my old code.

```
public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        DatawarehouseEntities db = new DatawarehouseEntities();

        // Get JSON from WebHook
        JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();


        var tableName = data["Table_Name"].ToString();
        var columnNames = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(String.Format("SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('{0}'); ", tableName)).ToList();
        var table = db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(db, null);

        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                           .SingleOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == "DSI.Data");

        var type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tableName);
        var dbset = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //var dbset = db.Set(type);

        var jsonParams = data.Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var selectedColumnNames = columnNames.Intersect(jsonParams);
        foreach (var columnName in selectedColumnNames)
        {
            var property = dbset.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == columnName);
            property.SetValue(dbset, data[columnName].ToString(), null);
        }

        db.Set(type).Add(dbset);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

Here's what I try to post http://localhost:port/api/webhooks/incoming/genericjson?code=secret&Table_Name=Table_Name. The type always comes back null. How can I select a table using the string that I pass in?

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier, faster and less error-prone enumerate your entity types and add them to a lookup.  EG

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> EntityTypesByName { get; }  = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        EntityTypesByName.Add(et.Name, et.ClrType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used a OnModelCreating before. Where would I put this code to be triggered?

Comment: OnModelCreating runs once for each DbContext type.  It's where you do the model configuration.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me.

```
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
{
    DatawarehouseEntities db = new DatawarehouseEntities();

    // Get JSON from WebHook
    JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();


    var tableName = data["Table_Name"].ToString();
    var columnNames = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(String.Format("SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('{0}'); ", tableName)).ToList();
    var table = db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(db, null);

    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SingleOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == "DSI.Data");

    var type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tableName);
    var dbset = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var jsonParams = data.Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    var selectedColumnNames = columnNames.Intersect(jsonParams);
    foreach (var columnName in selectedColumnNames)
    {
        var property = dbset.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == columnName);
        property.SetValue(dbset, data[columnName].ToString(), null);
    }

    db.Set(type).Add(dbset);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```